# add text before binded values while using ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a scenario where i need to display options in dropdown with binded value and some text prefix to it 
html:

```
    <select ng-model="rounds" ng-change="fnTopRating(rounds)" class="col-xs-4" ng-options="rounds for rounds in [1,2,3,4]">
       <option value=''>round wise</option>
       <option>Round {{rounds}}</option>
    </select>
```

but here i am not getting round 1,round 2... in drop down instead i am getting 1,2,3,4...

I am not clear with what is happening .
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first your syntax is a bit wrong. I'd recommend you to check the [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

To add a prefix in your options you should use single quotes, like this:

```
<select ng-model="rounds" ng-change="fnTopRating()" class="col-xs-4" ng-options="'round ' + r for r in [1,2,3,4]">
   <option value label="round wise"></option>
</select>
```

**Note:** You just need to use `$scope.rounds` in your `controller` to get the selected item in `fnTopRating()` `function`, you don't need to pass it as *parameter*.